# Execute application from other binary -> how to get Path safely?

Tags: rust

I have a workspace containing 2 binaries. For some reason, I want to execute one executable (B) from my already running binary (A).

The problem is getting the correct dir in which executable B lives. I now use `current_dir()` with a lot of joins to navigate myself to the right `Path`. I use that `Path` for `Command`. I don't like this approach because it is a bit error prone and fails if the working dir isn't correct.

I am wondering if there is a macro in which I can navigate to the right path and gives a compile time error when the dir changes. Now I get runtime errors when I make a change in my dirs. There is a macro `include_bytes` which already errors out when the file can not be found, I want something similar.

```
├── Cargo.toml <- workspace
├── a
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src 
│       └── main.rs <- I want to execute executable B from this executable
└── b
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        └── main.rs
```

So now I am doing stuff like this, which I don't really like because it can crash fairly easy at runtime:

```
let dir = current_dir().unwrap();

assert!(dir.ends_with("a"));

let b = dir
    .parent()
    .unwrap()
    .join("b");

// Command stuff
```

Comment: Beware that, even though when you are developing it you execute your program with `cargo run`, and you can also assume the workspace has the layout you mentioned, in production it wouldn't be the case. You would just give people a binary blob, so they'd just execute it with `./bloba`, and they could put it anywhere. It's up to the user to make sure calling `blobb` in a shell will actually work, and in that case you don't need to figure out the path by yourself.

Comment: I would call the functionality in code by direct function calls and not by command api. This would have even better performance. Why are you calling it by creating a separate process?

Answer (score 1):

Cargo does have support for the case when you have a *test* that wants to run a binary. If you have the package structure

```
a/
  Cargo.toml
  src/main.rs
  tests/b.rs
```

then when the test target `b` runs, it will see [an environment variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html) `CARGO_BIN_EXE_a` which contains the absolute path to the built `a` executable. But this only works for test (or benchmark) targets, not any other situation.

For the future, there is [an accepted RFC #3028 for “artifact dependencies”](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3028) which will make similar environment variables available for binaries from dependencies, on request. That might serve your needs better.

---

However, even the artifact dependencies mechanism is only really appropriate for test/development work. When a program is compiled, distributed, and installed “for real”, it will have been relocated somewhere on the recipient's computer, and *none of your current directory structure will exist.* If you want this to work, you have to plan:

- In system packages such as are common on Linux, the program will be installed in a consistent place (usually `/usr/bin/`) and you can just store that path in your program (preferably with a compile-time configuration from environment variables, so that packagers can control it).
- On macOS and probably some other “zero installation” program distribution situations, programs can be anywhere, and it's a reasonable choice to look up the directory of the current executable (with [`std::env::current_exe()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_exe.html) and assume the other executable is in the same directory.

  That will also work for running from inside your workspace, since all the executables will be in the `target/debug/` or `target/release/` directory. (But you should not assume this is a reasonable solution on *all* platforms; `current_exe()` can fail or return the “wrong” answer for various reasons.)